# using api area. ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my current project I'm using `backbone.js` as a frontend technology. Ans I should note that I'm still on `MVC3` but ready to move on;) Is it reasonable to create `api` area as data endpoint for my client part. Of course I can avoid it and leave just a plain controller in non-area, exterior part of my project. What is the best practice?

Comment: What do you expect to gain from sticking your ApiControllers in an API Area? That way they're still included in your website, where I think an API does not belong. I would create a separate project for the API controllers and link to that from your website project. For that you can ultimately just create an empty controller in your site that inherits from `YourApiControllerBase`.

Comment: @CodeCaster I disagree, this is an API he is using for his backbone-based client. His client is inherently bound to his MVC project, just as his API will be. If he is creating a general purpose API, then what you say is true. But I don't think he is.

Comment: This _general purpose_ gets reached easier in any project than you think. You just don't want a _data service_ in your _website project_. That's all I'm saying. If you add the slightest bit of reporting, external maintenance (non-web-UI or different website project for admin interface) or anything like that, you'll immediately benefit from not having to run the main website (project) in order to access your data layer.

Comment: True, but then there are other things to consider. For example if the API does just stay as a simple data persistence api for the client, then having everything in a separate project means you then have the added rigmarole of any duplicate configuration etc, all the duplicate setup, an extra project to deploy and host etc. But you are right in that it is a common occurrence for an API to outgrow it's original function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good practice to have a separate area for your client API that your backbone models interact with. Separation of concerns, readability and all that.

I would recommend using [WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api) for your API instead of standard MVC controllers though. It is easy to add via nuget, takes minimal config to set up, and it works well with Backbone's HTTP-Verb based approach to model CRUD operations.

If you are already planning on using WebAPI, then please ignore me! If you can't for whatever reason, then I would still say a separate area is a good approach.